# How to reset a char array to NULL (empty)

Tags: c, string, null, arrays

I am writing a code to rearrange the words in a string from back to front. I have first managed to arranged the characters from back to front but cannot seem to reset a string to null before swapping the second word in the string a second time and so on.

For example, with the input, "**What the hell is going on here**"

The output turns out to be,  "**here onre going ising hellg thelg Whatg**"

So the last letters of the previous word stay with the "tempWord" variable. How can I fix this?

```
void revString(char statement[]);

int main (void){

int index;
char tempWord[LENGTH];
char statement[LENGTH] = "What the hell is going on here";
const char s[2] = " ";
char *word;
int wordCounter = 0;


revString(statement);

printf("%s\n", statement);              //Temp printing
```

(Just so it's clear, the code I'm asking about is below this line)

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
index = 0;
word = strtok(statement, s);

while (word != NULL){
    wordCounter++;

    for (index = 0; index <= strlen(word); index++){
        tempWord[index] = '\0';
    }

    strcpy(tempWord, word);

    revString(tempWord);

    printf("%s ", tempWord);

    word = strtok(NULL, s);

}
printf("\n");
printf("%d words", wordCounter);

}
```

Let me know what you think!

```
void revString(char original[]){

int index;
char temp[LENGTH];
int j = 1;

for (index = 0; index < strlen(original); index++, j++){
    temp[(strlen(original) - j)] = original[index];
}

strcpy(original, temp);
original[strlen(original)] = '\0';

}
```

Comment: In `revString()`, the terminating null character is never set for `temp`.

Comment: BTW: If you only want to reverese the order of the words, try a double-reverse: First, reverse the whole string. Next, reverse each word.

Comment: What is `original[strlen(original)] = '\0'` good for??? This is the chicken-egg paradox!!!

Comment: this code block: for (index = 0; index <= strlen(word); index++){
        tempWord[index] = '\0';
    }  would be better written as: memset( tempWord, 0x00, sizof tempWord );

Comment: Thank you all for your help! My goal was to do a double reverse, actually. The print above the dashed line gives the full string reverse while the block below was intended to reverse each word.

Comment: I actually ended up going after it from a different approach. I found the last 'space' in the original string and printed from there to the end and replaced it with a NULL character, then found the next space and printed to the NULL character. I just repeated this until the beginning of the string. Conveniently, this was the whole assignment. Reversing the words was the final step in the process. Otherwise I would have had to use one of your suggestions, so thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is temp is not terminated with '\0'.

I modified the revString and tweaked a bit (called strlen only once)...

void revString(char original[]){

```
int index;
char temp[LENGTH];
int j = 1;
int len = strlen(original);

temp[len] = '\0';
for (index = 0; index < len; index++, j++){
        temp[len - j] = original[index];
}

strcpy(original, temp);
original[len] = '\0';
```

}

Interestingly your original code doesn't give me a problem for LENGTH values from 30 to 100. For more than 200 bytes values it gives me strange characters (possibly the garbage) which got me into setting the last character in string "temp" to NULL.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks muchly! It hadn't occurred to me that it wouldn't add the NULL character automatically. Will I always have to add that character?

Answer (score 0):

Set the terminating Null character for tempword, according to the length of word
i.e.

```
while (word != NULL){
    wordCounter++;

    strcpy(tempWord, word);
    revString(tempWord);
    tempWord[strlen(word)] = '\0';
    printf("%s ", tempWord);

    word = strtok(NULL, s);

   }
printf("\n");
printf("%d words", wordCounter);

}
```